# signing an apk in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, code-signing

I am new to AndroidStudio and I have a fully functional AndroidProject in Eclipse, which I try to migrate to AndroidStudio.

Actually I have a signing problem when starting the app.
It says : The apk for the currently selected variant is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant (demo).

In Project Structure -> Tab : Signing I added a new Signing entry. For this i filled all 4 fields correctly. 
I also checked the keystore and alias with :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin\keytool" -list -keystore "C:\eclipse\keystore\mykeystore" -alias myalias
```

which was successfull.

But still I get this error.

I use also build variants (DEMO, FULL, TEST) and I am not sure if I have to assign the signings to variants ?

I am able to sign an app with using "build" -> "Generate Signed APK" , but not when starting the app.

Can someone help ?

Comment: see this if it helps http://ftcforum.usfirst.org/showthread.php?6739-error-on-Android-Studio-2-0-or-2-1

Comment: Sorry for wasting all your time, I guess I just found it. Under Variants I have to assign a signing Config to my individuall Variant.

Answer (score 0):

You created the signing config. Now, you need to specify this sign for the build variants. Project structure -> Build types -> Signing config

[image]